# Angular Passing an array of data from one module to another

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a grid with list of information that user can select. Once the user selects certain rows, these rows should be passed to a different page as a summary and also for more operations.

> For example, there is list of transaction pulled from backend. User
> can select certain transactions from the grid. These selected
> transaction are then transferred to another page as a summary to do
> costing management.
>
> Transaction List Page -> Costing Management Page

How do I pass these selected list from the first module to second module?

Angular version : 11

Comment: The easiest way is to use a service registered with a root provider https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services  Understanding services and DI is a key component of angular.   Generally speaking, services are shared across components as a single instance.

Comment: @RaySuelzer  This one worked, Would yo mind putting this as the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on if your Costing Management Page should persist the data when the page is refreshed.

### **Services**

If you do not want data to be persisted on page refreshes, you can go down the route of [Single Shared instance of the Service](https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services) provided at the root. This service instance will be injected by angular within any component you may use.

### **NavigationExtras**

Personally, I would prefer my application to be stateless at all times if possible. So putting data in the services are lost on page refreshes.

By putting data in `QueryParams`, you maintain the state of the application at all times like when the page is refreshed, the link is shared, added to favourites etc.

If you want a more focused way of passing the data between routes, you can use [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras#state). This does not require you to create a singleton service, subscription etc. This was introduced in Angular 7 for mainly the purposes you have mentioned.

Comment: Can you clarify which property of `NavigationExtras` you are talking about? All the properties I see are encoded into the URL, so I don't see the part that will be lost?

Comment: You are right. The data property of `NavigationExtras` does encode the data in the URL. I was thinking about `state` property of `NavigationExtras` which is not part of the URL. But that doesn't really matter in this context as we use the `data` property anyway. Brain freeze moment I guess. I have edited the answer now.